# Filtering Functionality Similar to Ebay SQL Count Issue

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am stuck on a database problem for a client, wandering if someone could help me out. I am currently trying to implement filtering functionality so that a user can filter results after they have searched for something. We are using SQL Server 2008. I am working on an electronics e-commerce site and the database is quite large (500,000 plus records). The scenario is this - user goes to our website and types in 'laptop' and clicks search. This brings up the first page of several thousand results. What I want to do is then
filter these results further and present the user with options such as:

### Filter By Manufacturer

Dell (10,000)
Acer (2,000)
Lenovo (6,000)

### Filter By Colour

Black (7000)
Silver (2000)

The main columns of the database are like this - the primary key is an integer ID

**ID    Title  Manufacturer    Colour**

The key part of the question is how to get the counts in various categories in an efficient manner. The only way I currently know how to do it is with separate queries. However, should we wish to filter by further categories then this will become very slow - especially as the database grows. My current SQL is this:

```
select count(*) as ManufacturerCount, Manufacturer from [ProductDB.Product] GROUP BY Manufacturer;
select count(*) as ColourCount, Colour from [ProductDB.Product] GROUP BY Colour;
```

My question is if I can get the results as a single table using some-kind of join or union and if this would be faster than my current method of issuing multiple queries with the Count(*) function. Thanks for your help, if you require any further information please ask. PS I am wandering how on sites like ebay and amazon manage to do this so fast. In order to understand my problem better if you go onto ebay and type in laptop you will
see a number of filters on the left - this is basically what I am trying to achieve. I don't know how it can be done efficiently when there are many filters. E.g to get functionality equivalent to Ebay I would need about 10 queries and I'm sure that will be slow. I was thinking of creating an intermediate table with all the counts however the intermediate table would have to be continuously updated in order to reflect changes to the database and that would be a problem if there are multiple updates per minute. Thanks.

Comment: Research "faceted search". Sql Server is fine for small project, but at large scale you would want to use back-end built for this purpose, such as SOLR or ElasticSearch

Answer (score 0):

The "intermediate table" is exactly the way to go.  I can guarantee you that no e-commerce site with substantial traffic and large number of products would do what you are suggesting on the fly at every inquiry.

If you are worried about keeping track of changes to products, just do all changes to the product catalog thru stored procs (my preferred method) or else use triggers.

One complication is how you will group things in the intermediate table.  If you are only grouping on pre-defined categories and sub-categories that are built into the product hierarchy, then it's fairly easy.  It sounds like you are allowing free-text search... if so, how will you manage multiple keywords that result in an unexpected intersection of different categories?  One way is to save the keywords searched along with the counts and a time stamp.  Then, the next time someone searches on the same keywords, check the intermediate table and if the time stamp is older than some predetermined threshold (say, 5 minutes), return your results to a temp table, query the category counts from the temp table, overwrite the previous counts with the new time stamp, and return the whole enchilada to the web app.  Otherwise, skip the temp table and just return the pre-aggregated counts and data records.  In this case, you might get some quirky front-end count behavior, like it might say "10 results" in a particular category but then when the user drills down, they actually find 9 or 11.  It's happened to me on different sites as a customer and it's really not a big deal.

BTW, I used to work for a well-known e-commerce company and we did things like this.

Comment: ok, thanks for your comment. What about the main query i.e when the user has searches for 'laptop' does that query use temp tables?

Comment: You should check your "intermediate table" and if the counts are already there and not stale, use those & do not use a temp table for the main query, just return that data directly to the web app.  If the counts are not in the intermediate table or are stale, then query your main data into a temp table, get your category counts from the temp table, store them in the intermediate table, then return to the user the data from the temp table along with the counts.

Comment: ok thanks. Just out of interest do you think sql server 2008 is a good bet for a site that has big data? Im not so sure. Don't other databases have faster search and paging?

Comment: would you know how to speed up following query on sql server 2008 - takes approx 2 seconds but wanting it to be faster, same db as above. WITH RowsTable AS
(
    SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ct.[RANK] DESC)) AS RowNum, e.* 
    FROM CONTAINSTABLE ([Web.ProductDB], title, 'dell') As ct 
    JOIN [WebCMS.Product] As e ON ct.[KEY] = e.ID
    WHERE (ct.[RANK] > 0)
)
SELECT title,Manufacturer,DescpTop
FROM RowsTable
WHERE (RowNum >= 1) AND (RowNum < 21)